# Use of __EVENTARGUMENT in postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, dom-events

This may be a basic question. I know `__doPostback()` function accepts 2 arguments, `eventtarget` and `eventargs`. `eventtarget` is used to identify the control that causes postback. Then what is the use of `eventargs` in `__doPostback` function?

I saw the `__doPostback` function always set the `__EVENTARGUMENT` hidden field to nothing for any postbacks caused by controls with even autopostback to true or a control like linkButton.

Please give me your input.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to assign the _EVENTARGUMENT you can manually invoke the postback with javascript:

```
  javascript:__doPostBack('MyControl', 'myArgument');
```

This site explains how ASP.NET uses the postback mechanism: http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.5

Answer (score 2):

The `__EVENTARGUMENT` is any relevant event arguments regarding the control performing the postback. For most controls, there are no specialized event arguments, and since event arguments are different for every control, `null` is passed to represent a default argument should be created during the event sequence.

Try watching the `__EVENTARGUMENT` that gets passed when you have a specialized control (such as a linkbutton in a gridview that has commandname/commandargument/etc assigned). You should begin to see values getting passed.

Comment: Hi Joel,
Thanks for the reply. i tried adding a LinkButton in a template column with commonad name assiged but still the rendered html has nothing for eventargs,see the below html output from a grdiview,

 <a id="gvUsers_ctl03_lb" href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvUsers$ctl03$lb','')">Edit</a>

Comment: Is there a way to have more than one event argument?

Comment: @Wilson: Not as separate parameters. You could set your command argument or name to be a parameter that is a string with a pattern that could be split into meaningful parameters.